# Why can't I use this.getClass in auxiliary constructor in scala?

Tags: scala, constructor

Why can't I use this.getClass in auxiliary constructor in scala? Are there any alternatives?

More specifically, I am trying to call LoggerFactory.getLogger of slf4j in the auxiliary constructor. I have an hack now where I am forced to pass a logger object to the constructor.

A simple contrived example (does not compile) which shows what I am trying to do:

```
class A (numbers : Double) {
   val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)

   def this(numbersAsStr: String) = this (try { s.toDouble) } catch { case _ => LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass).error("Failed to convert");  0 }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually a limitation of the JVM rather than specifically a Scala problem. Here's a similar example in Java:

```
public class ThisTest {

  public final String name;

  public ThisTest(String n) {
    name = n;
  }

  public ThisTest() {
    // trying to use `this` in a call to the primary constructor
    this(this.getClass().getName());
  }

}
```

When you try to compile it you get an error:

```
$ javac ThisTest.java
ThisTest.java:10: error: cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called
    this(this.getClass().getName());
         ^
1 error
```

The problem is that you're trying to reference `this` before `this` any of the super-constructors for `this` have been called. You will have the restriction that you can't use a `this` reference in a `super()` or `this()` call no matter what JVM language you use, because that's the way classes work on the JVM.

However, you can totally avoid this problem by restructuring your code to put the reference to `this` *after* the `this()` call:

```
class A (numbers: Double) {
   val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)

   def this(numbersAsStr: String) = {
     this ( try { numbersAsStr.toDouble } catch { case _ => 0 } )
     LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass).error("Failed to convert");
   }
}
```

You might actually want access to the thrown exception for your log info. In that case, I'd just use `LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[A])`. That won't give you the actual class name if you're using inheritance (which I was assuming was the case here), but if you include the stack trace in the log then you should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question. Here is a guess:

```
class Foo(val c: Class[_]) {
  def this() = this(classOf[Foo])
}

new Foo().c  // -> class Foo
```

Comment: Won't work for sub-classing, which is very likely the intent here.